# MassTransit Integration Test

Tags: c#, testing, request, integration, masstransit

Is not already implemented a method to test the send and receive of a request with MassTransit between two different services?

I'm building an API which need to send a request with MassTransit. The implementation is correct and I've already seen this. But when I try to test it, I see that the request reach the consumer and then it can't come back.

(Edit #1)
Here below I add my relevants code's part:

TestClass:

```
[TestClass]
    public class UnbindVisilibityTests : InfrastructureDataTestBase
    {
        private readonly InfrastructureDataTestDal _infrastructureDal = new InfrastructureDataTestDal();
        private ITestHarness _harness;
        private ServiceProvider _provider;

        UnbindVisibilityCommand command;

        int idVis;

        [TestInitialize]
        public void Init()
        {
            _provider = new ServiceCollection()
                .AddMassTransitTestHarness(cfg =>
                {
                    cfg.AddConsumer<UnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequestConsumer>();
                    cfg.AddBus(context =>
                    {
                        return Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(configure =>
                        {
                            // Configura il bus in-memory
                            configure.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                        });
                    });
                })
                .BuildServiceProvider(true);

            _harness = _provider.GetRequiredService<ITestHarness>();

            idVis = _infrastructureDal.InsertVisibility("UnbindVisibilityCommandTest", "TestAppl");

            command = new UnbindVisibilityCommand
            {
                Id = idVis,
            };
        }

        [TestMethod]
        public async Task Unbind_OK()
        {
            await _harness.Start();

            var result = Mediator.Send(command).Result;

            Assert.IsTrue(result is SuccessCommandResult);

            await _harness.Stop();
        }

        [TestCleanup]
        public void CleanUpTest()
        {
            _infrastructureDal.DeleteVisibility(new int[] { idVis });
        }
    }
```

Consumer:

```
public class UnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequestConsumer : IConsumer<IUnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequest>
    {
        private readonly IApplicativeUsersCommandDal _dal;

        public UnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequestConsumer(IApplicativeUsersCommandDal dal)
        {
            _dal = dal;
        }

        public async Task Consume(ConsumeContext<IUnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequest> context)
        {
            await _dal.UnbindUsersFromVisibilityAsync(context.Message.Id);

            await context.RespondAsync<IUnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterResult>(new { });
        }
    }
```

Configuration:

```
public abstract class InfrastructureDataTestBase : TestBase
    {
        internal static IMediator Mediator;
        protected IServiceProvider serviceProvider;
        static bool _isInitialized;
        public IConfiguration configuration;

        public InfrastructureDataTestBase()
        {
            var builder = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                  .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + ".\\InfrastructureData.Tests")
                  .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                  .AddJsonFile("TokenVerificationSettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
                  .AddEnvironmentVariables();

            configuration = builder.Build();

            if (_isInitialized == false)
            {
                serviceProvider = GetServiceProvider(configuration);

                Mediator = serviceProvider.GetService<IMediator>();
            }
        }

        public IServiceProvider GetServiceProvider(IConfiguration config)
        {
            ServiceCollection services = new ServiceCollection();

            services.AddControllers();

            DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlClientFactory.Instance);

            services.AddSwaggerApiVersioning<ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();

            var connProvider = ConnectionStringProviderFactory.CreateInstance(config.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStringFullFilePath"), config.GetValue<string>("RsaKeyFullFilePath"));

            services.AddSingleton(connProvider);

            services.AddLogging();

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);

            services.AddPagingProvider();

            services.AddHealthChecks();

            services.AddOptions(config);

            services.AddAccessTokenValidation();

            services.AddIdentityProvider(configuration.GetValue<string>("IDP.BaseUri"));

            services.AddApplicationLayer();

            services.AddDataInfrastructureLayer(configuration, connProvider);

            ConfigureServices(services, configuration);

            MessageBrokerOptions messageBrokerOptions = new();

            config.GetSection(MessageBrokerOptions.SectionName).Bind(messageBrokerOptions);

            services.AddMassTransit(x =>
            {
                x.AddMassTransitTestHarness(x =>
                {
                    x.AddDelayedMessageScheduler();

                    x.AddConsumer<UnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequestConsumer>();
                });
                x.AddConsumer<UnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequestConsumer>();

                x.UsingRabbitMq((context, cfg) =>
                {
                    cfg.Host(messageBrokerOptions.HostName, (ushort)messageBrokerOptions.Port, messageBrokerOptions.VirtualHost, h =>
                    {
                        var rsaFile = config.GetValue<string>("RsaKeyFullFilePath");

                        var cryptoService = string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(rsaFile)
                            ? Digitronica.IT.Infrastructure.Security.Cryptography.CryptoService.CreateDefault()
                            : Digitronica.IT.Infrastructure.Security.Cryptography.CryptoService.CreateFromXmlFile(rsaFile);

                        h.Username(messageBrokerOptions.Username);
                        h.Password(cryptoService.Decrypt(messageBrokerOptions.Password));
                    });

                    cfg.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });

                x.AddRequestClient<IUnbindUsersFromVisibilityFilterRequest>();
            });

            _isInitialized = true;

            return services.BuildServiceProvider();
        }
    }
```

```
public abstract class TestBase
    {
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services, IConfiguration config)
        {
            services.AddControllers();

            DbProviderFactories.RegisterFactory("System.Data.SqlClient", SqlClientFactory.Instance);

            services.AddSwaggerApiVersioning<ConfigureSwaggerOptions>();

            services.AddConnectionStringProvider(config.GetValue<string>("ConnectionStringFullFilePath"), config.GetValue<string>("RsaKeyFullFilePath"));

            services.AddLogging();

            services.AddSingleton<IConfiguration>(config);

            services.AddPagingProvider();

            services.AddHealthChecks();

            services.AddOptions(config);

            services.AddAccessTokenValidation();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you provide your integration test code?

Comment: I updated my question with some code's parts. If something is missing that can be helpful tell me